# Spring Boot and JPA: error returning data from a multi-join query to a GET HTTP command

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm on Spring Boot and JPA since few weeks, so maybe the question is relatively trivial to someone. I have an @Entity where I defined a @NamedNativeQuery like:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Device.getMeasuresAndDates",
        query = """
        select a.id, 
        a.device,
        a.deviceManufacturer, 
        b.dateOfMeasure, 
        c.Id, 
        c.componentSerialNumber, 
        c.ComponentMeasure
        from devices a inner join measures b on b.device_id = a.id
        inner join instruments c on c.id = b.instrument_id
        where a.device = :device
        order by b.dateOfMeasure, c.componentSerialNumber
        """,
        resultSetMapping = "MeasuresAndDatesMapping"
        )
```

the query is defined in the Device entity, as it seems to be the logical place where to put it.
The query returns only proper fields, not all the entities fields that are much more, and most of them are useless to the service.

then I tried to map the results with @SqlResultSetMapping + @EntityResult; since I do not return all table fields, I do not map all entity properties,
I put the entity property names in "name" attribute and the field returned by the query in "column" attribute:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "MeasuresAndDatesMapping",
        entities = {
            @EntityResult(
                    entityClass = Device.class,
                    fields = {
                        @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "a.id"),
                        @FieldResult(name = "device", column = "a.device"),
                        @FieldResult(name = "deviceManufacturer", column = "a.deviceManufacturer")
                    }
            ),
            @EntityResult(
                entityClass = Measure.class,
                fields = {
                    @FieldResult(name = "dateOfMeasure", column = "b.dateOfMeasure")
                }
            ),
            @EntityResult(
                    entityClass = Component.class,
                    fields = {
                        @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "c.id"),
                        @FieldResult(name = "componentSerialNumber", column = "c.componentSerialNumber"),
                        @FieldResult(name = "componentMeasure", column = "c.ComponentMeasure")
                    }
            )
        }
    )
```

then I mapped the query to the  JPA repository defined for Device:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, name="Device.getMeasuresAndDates") 
public List<Object> LetturePerPod(@Param("device") String device);
```

First, I'm not sure what type has to be returned by the interface method.
Second, I do not know if it's correct to define such a method in the interface. But if I want to define the method directly in the entity class, I have to access the EntityManager to use the @NamedNativeQuery, but that is not possible from within the class.
I aim to keep the architecture as clean as possible, leveraging JPA and avoiding any tricky solutions.

Anyway, doing things this way I get this error:

```
Cannot createTypedQuery for query with more than one return
```

I guess it would work only if I return all fields of all entities, like

```
select
a.*,
b.*,
c.*
from
```

so which is the right approach to the problem?

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: And what is the error you've got?

Comment: Sorry, yes error it's not clear: the error is Cannot createTypedQuery for query with more than one return, I don't get what it means. the "more than one return" is confusing me

Comment: Does the error tell you which columns are in the multiple returns?

Comment: Why are you using a native query ? There's nothing special in you query. A named query should do the job.

Comment: I've been using Spring for a couple of weeks, so copying and pasting a query from an Oracle package to a native query seemed to be the easiest thing to do. But you are right, I should try a named query

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that it's your column "id" which is duplicated in a and c.
Just like in sql you could just add an alias to the duplicated columns.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "Device.getMeasuresAndDates",
    query = """
    select a.id as aid, 
    a.device,
    a.deviceManufacturer, 
    b.dateOfMeasure, 
    c.Id as cid, 
    c.componentSerialNumber, 
    c.ComponentMeasure
    from devices a inner join measures b on b.device_id = a.id
    inner join instruments c on c.id = b.instrument_id
    where a.device = :device
    order by b.dateOfMeasure, c.componentSerialNumber
    """,
    resultSetMapping = "MeasuresAndDatesMapping"
    )
```

PS: SQL doesn't care about uppercase Id and ID and id is the exact same field.

Comment: yes, this is one error. Fixed this, the error message turns into "Invalid column name". I made some changes and got it to work this way: I removed all EntityResult except the one for Device. Then I mapped each and every entity attribute of Device class to a column from the query. This works. If I remove one FieldResult it gives the "Invalid column name". So I tried to map all attributes of Device and all attributes of Measure, but I get back to the initial "Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return".